# How to Find Which Unique Table Index a SQL Full Text Index Uses

Tags: sql-server-2005

How do you discover the name of the unique table index a full text index references? SQL to generate the response would be most useful, but GUI (SSMS) solution will work too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This query should do it - works on SQL Server 2005 and up:

```
SELECT 
    OBJECT_NAME(fti.object_id) AS 'Table Name',
    i.name AS 'Index Name',
    c.name AS 'Column Name'
FROM 
    sys.fulltext_indexes fti
INNER JOIN 
    sys.index_columns ic ON ic.object_id = fti.object_id AND ic.index_id = fti.unique_index_id
INNER JOIN 
    sys.columns c ON c.object_id = ic.object_id AND c.column_id = ic.column_id
INNER JOIN
    sys.indexes i ON fti.unique_index_id = i.index_id AND fti.object_id = i.object_id
```

Marc